# Switch to another user and source personal bashrc file

Tags: bash, sudo

As user *aa*, I need to login to an shared account *bb*. After I login as *bb*, I want to source the personal bashrc file which is only used by myself, not any other users. How could I make this happen in one line command? I find some possible answers like

```
sudo -iu bb bash -c 'source bashrc_aa'
```

but after this it will change back to user *aa*, I want to keep as user *bb*. Any solutions?

Comment: Why not simply `su bb`? This should automatically source the `.bashrc`

Comment: @Panki They appear to have a separate file that they want to source (in addition to the usual shell startup files).

Comment: Can we assume that you would want to do this _without_ modifying the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files of the `bb` account?

Comment: take a look at --rcfile option of bash.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes and no. At first I don't want ot modify `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` as i just want it only affect to my account `aa`, but as suggested by @terdon below. We can still limit the change to my account only with `.bashrc` modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you could simply modify bb's `.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` if that exists) to source the .bashrc file of whatever user is running the `sudo` command:

```
if [[ -n $SUDO_USER ]]; then
    . /home/"$SUDO_USER"/.bashrc 
fi
```

Or, if you can't assume the home directory will be at `/home/user_name`, you could read it from `/etc/passwd`:

```
if [[ -n $SUDO_USER ]]; then
    homeDir=$(awk -F':' -v s="$SUDO_USER" '$1==s{print $6}' /etc/passwd)
    . "$homeDir"/.bashrc 
fi
```

This will apply to all users who `sudo` into `bb`, but in each case it will source *their* bashrc. Alternatively, you could make the change for your user only:

```
if [[ $SUDO_USER == "aa" ]]; then
    . /home/aa/.bashrc 
fi
```

Comment: `getent passwd "$SUDO_USER" | cut -d: -f6`, the ways are many.

Comment: great, it works for my issue.

Comment: @ceasers Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda for the advice.