# Source user config when becoming root

Tags: zsh, sudo

My default user account has `zsh` set as the preferred shell. I have done some configuration in the `.zshrc` file, which is all fine and well.

However, once I become `root` by running `sudo -s`, I get a `zsh` instance without any configuration. I can now run `source ~/.zshrc` to get my aliases etc. back, but I'd rather have this be the default action. The same goes for `.vimrc` and such.

How can I accomplish this?

Moving `.zshrc` and other configs to `/root/` is out of the question, as I am not the only `sudoer` on this system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch to another user and source personal bashrc file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530841/switch-to-another-user-and-source-personal-bashrc-file)

Comment: @muru I would prefer to not change stuff in `/root` - however, I do understand that I could check in there if the user is myself. This feels wrong to me...

Comment: Then run something like `sudo env ZDOTDIR=$HOME zsh -l` to have it source files from your home directory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the sudo configuration, it may either keep the `HOME` environment variable pointing to your home directory or make it point to the home directory of the target user. It may make a difference whether you run `sudo -s` or `sudo zsh` (again, depending on the sudo configuration).

To always keep your home directory, you can use

```
sudo --preserve-env=HOME
```

if sudo's configuration allows it, or

```
sudo env HOME="$HOME" zsh
```

which is always possible.

You may want to make this an alias or a function, e.g.

```
alias sudo='sudo --preserve-env=HOME'
```

or

```
function sudo {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    set env HOME="$HOME" zsh
  fi
  sudo "$@"
}
```

Beware that some applications save state files in your home directory, and you may end up with some root-owned files, for example `.viminfo` and `.zsh_history`. If only a few programs are problematic, configure them to use different state files. For example, I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
" Disable viminfo if running as root
if has("unix")
  if system("id -u") == 0
    set viminfo=
  endif
endif
```

And (a more complex version of) this in my `.zshrc`:

```
if [[ $UID -eq 0 ]]; then
  HISTFILE="${HISTFILE%_history}_root_history"
fi
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - exceptional. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Side effects: files in your home directory might get owned by root (e.g., if you have set Vim to have undofiles located somewhere in your home directory)

Comment: @muru Good point, I added some tips about this.