# How to automatically source your bashrc file when you become a root user

Tags: bash, centos, rhel, root

At my work work we work with multiple people on several RHEL servers.

I always login to my Linux servers as my regular user (duh).
Assume I have a added extra functions/aliases to my `.bashrc` file. Is there any way that I can keep my `.bashrc` when I elevate to the root user? Maybe by putting a command/alias in my `.bashrc` that sources my original user's `.bashrc` when I change?

What's the best method to do this. Without causing issues to other users that are logged in.

So login as `user1`, do `sudo su -`, but keep the aliases and functions of `user1`.

Comment: Or how about https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632423/source-user-config-when-becoming-root

Comment: just : `source ~user1/.bashrc`  ? You could even maybe create a function for that : `function sourceme { local original_user=$( who am i | cut -d' ' -f1 ); eval "original_dir=~${original_user}" ; source "$original_dir/.bashrc" ;}` # I can not test this right now. "who am i" will  show the 1st login's name, instead of the current name (whoami shows the latter)

Comment: Why `sudo su -`? Just use `sudo -i` - there's no need for the `su` part at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using local accounts, add this to the root bashrc....

```
if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]; then
   OLDHOME="$( getent passwd "$SUDO_USER" | cut -f 6 -d':' )"
   if [ -f "${OLDHOME}/.bashrc" ]; then
      source "${OLDHOME}/.bashrc"
   fi
fi
```

before or after the definitions already there depending on the behaviour you want.

Comment: I'd strongly consider taking root access away from anyone who unilaterally added that to root's `bashrc` if there were multiple admins expecting to access that root account.  NFW would I countenance polluting a shared root account with personal envvals just because one admin felt that was needed.

Comment: I wouldn't give root access to someone I did not trust to communicate / discuss such changes.

Answer (score -1):

On my system you can simply use `sudo -s`. It will give you a root shell but won't change the `$HOME` directory - so for a `bash` shell you'll get your own `$HOME/.bashrc` invoked. (Setting `$HOME` for a simple `sudo -s` is a configurable option in `/etc/sudoers`, so it might be different for you. Try comparing `sudo -s` and `sudo -sH`. If they're different it will work for you, but if they give the same result you'll need a [different solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771801/100397).)

I added a line like this to each of `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` where they already existed for my own account and root's account, editing the text so that `.bash_profile` was replaced appropriately each time according to the file name:

```
test -t 2 && echo "> This is $HOME/.bash_profile for ${USER:-unknown}" >&2
```

Logged in as me (`roaima`):

```
sudo -s
>> This is /home/roaima/.bashrc for root
# _
```

Back to me again (`roaima`):

```
sudo -sH
>> This is /root/.bashrc for root
```

And back to me again (`roaima`) one last time:

```
sudo -i
>> This is /root/.profile for root
>> This is /root/.bashrc for root
# _
```